# How can I prevent a new paragraph between two \input commands?

Tags: paragraphs, input

I want to use the command `\input{}` to insert two textfiles, `text1.tex` and `text2.tex`, into my latex working file. I want these two textfiles to produce one single paragraph when I am compiling my working file. However, when I place

```
\input{text1.tex}\input{text2.tex}
```

in a single line in the working file, the content of the two text files still ends up in two different paragraphs in the compiled text. I have tried to put the command `\nolinebreak` between the two `\input{}` commands without success.

So, how can I prevent a new paragraph to be produced between the two textfiles?

Comment: it produces one paragraph for me. Helps to add a trailing `%` as in `\input{text1.tex}%`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the empty line in `text1.tex` or `text2.tex` which produces the new paragraph. –